# Caps_Lock changed to Multi_key

Tags: debian, capslock

As seen via `xev`, in my user session the CapsLock key (keycode 66) is bound to `Multi_key`.  Whereas in another user (guest) session it is bound to `Caps_Lock`.

In a terminal I've tried

```
setxkbmap -option caps:capslock
```

but nothing changes.

Running `showkey` on a text console and pressing the CapsLock key gives keycode 58. The default console keymap file `/etc/console/boottime.kmap.gz` has the following line:

```
keycode  58 = Caps_Lock
```

How can I make the CapsLock key be bound to `Caps_Lock` again?

Comment: Just tried it but nothing changed.

Comment: Dont confuse X11 keycodes with console codes. Try the same with 66 instead of 58.

Comment: You mean to try what?